# how to use a letter/string present in a text box as a trigger to get a pop up window in ms access using vb?

Tags: vba, popup

I'm looking for code which uses a letter or a string present in a text box as trigger to open a pop up window saying "it's unilateral " after the form populates in ms access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

In the event

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()

End Sub
```

Add code

```
If InStr(Text1.Text, "A") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "It's unilateral"
End If
```

Comment: message box does not pop up when the text box populates.

Comment: @Mahesh Gowda what software are you writing you vba in?